# Not able to see logs in GCP logging?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

Since last week we are not able to see the logs in the tab of logging of Google Cloud Console. It sometimes works and show logs for a few mins, after that it will show the logs entry and need to be opened explicitly to see.I even posted this issue to Google Cloud platform but still no positive out come.  Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Even hard cache reloading the tab or even opening the tab on other browsers has the same result.

It should show the logs on tabs where now only blank tab is showing.[image]

Comment: Hi. @Rajat. What are the permissions of your user? Does it happen for another user with the permissions owner? What is the product that experience the issue (all ot them)? [Please check the docs about the permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control)

Answer (score 2):

Error in progress on Google side. Here their provided workaround

> We' re still working on releasing the fix, but in the meantime as a
>   workaround I suggest that you add the text payload field as a custom
>   field:
>   1. Select View Options > Modify custom fields
>   2. In the dialog enter "textPayload" as a custom field and uncheck "Limit custom field width"
>
> Unfortunately custom fields aren't persisted by default, but you can
>   save them as part of a saved search if you want.

Comment: Hey @Rajat Lutade, can you confirm that this is now working for you? If so, can you mark this as an accepted answer, so it gets greater visibility to the community? Thanks